# How to play a sound attached to an Image Array using Swift 3.0?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, audio, imageview

Is it possible to play a sound when Image-5 is called in the following Image Array

Here is the complete code including setting up the AVAudioPlayer

ImageArray and the code you suggested:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var player:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()    

    var imagesName = ["Image-1.png","Image-2.png","Image-3.png","Image-4.png","Image-5.png","Image-6.png","Image-7.png","Image-8.png","Image-9.png","Image-10.png"]

            var images = [UIImage]()

            for i in 0..<imagesName.count{

                images.append(UIImage(named: imagesName[i])!)

            }

            imageView.animationImages = images
            imageView.animationDuration = 0.5
            imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1
            imageView.startAnimating()

            do
    {
        let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "song", ofType: "mp3")
        try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!) as URL)
    }
    catch
    {
        //ERROR
    }

    let whichImage: Int = 5
    let when = DispatchTime.now() + imageView.animationDuration * TimeInterval(whichImage-1)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
        self.player.play()
        // Play sound here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you interval is fixed you kinda already know when the Image-5 will be fired, so try this:

```
let whichImage: Int = 5
let when = DispatchTime.now() + imageView.animationDuration * TimeInterval(whichImage-1)
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
    // Play sound here
}
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for the help.  I have updated the complete code above, however the song.mp3 does not fire when Image-5 is displayed - it fires a few seconds after the animation is finished

Comment: You're using 0.5 seconds per image so the delay should be 2.5 seconds, not 5 seconds. However the sound play start might not synchronize perfectly with displaying the image.

Comment: Hi Ruslan Serebriakov - I have tried your suggested code (please see above) but it looks like there is a 2-3 second delay the first time you play an audio file with AVAudioPlayer, do you have any additional thoughts?

Comment: Hi @DuncanC - do you have any thoughts on how to better sync up the AVAudioPlayer?